# How could I allow content editors to send email to a selected bunch of users?

Tags: emails, views

I have a content editor that wants to be able to send emails on a regular basis to a selected bunch of users. Could I create a view of all site users and use [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) for this?

Answer (score 2):

If your content editors need to be able to select the group they are contacting  you can use [Views Send](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_send). You can also use [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) (and probably [Views Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rules) to ease the process of writing the rule some) particullarly if the editors are not going to be editing the message (if they are sending a notice about content updates or something similar).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the [Views Send](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_send) module.

It sends an email for each row and you can use tokens for the body and subject. I think it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

Just install the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module and use the delivered sample **Active Users Email**, locáted in relative path `/reports/drupaladmin.sample_active_users_letter`.

Adapt the template for the actual eMail body to fit your needs.